# spark 3.2.0 the different dataframe createOrReplaceTempView the same name TempView

Tags: scala, apache-spark

code show as below:

```
val sparkSession = DataExtract.getSparkSession("testName")
sparkSession.sql("use hive")
val df1 = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * from test1 ")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("test1")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("test1")
val df = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * from test1 ")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test1")
```

When I execute this code, the first time I execute the `createOrReplaceTempView` method is successful, and then use the same dataframe to execute the `createOrReplaceTempView` method again is also successful, but when I use another dataframe to `createOrReplaceTempView` with the same name Report an error, the error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Recursive view `test1` detected (cycle: `test1` -> `test1`)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.recursiveViewDetectedError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:2045)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ViewHelper$.checkCyclicViewReference(views.scala:515)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ViewHelper$.$anonfun$checkCyclicViewReference$2(views.scala:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ViewHelper$.$anonfun$checkCyclicViewReference$2$adapted(views.scala:522)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:944)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:944)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1432)
```

This problem has troubled me for a long time. There was no such problem in the previous version of `spark3.1.1`. It suddenly appeared after the upgraded version. I hope someone can help me. I'm very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: spark3.2.0    scala2.12

Comment: Why do you want to create many temporary views at all? You could instead use the more typesafe scala native LINQ style API of the data frames and would be totally fine.

Comment: I've raised this as an issue against the main Spark repo [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37690). I'm not sure whether it's intentional or a bug, hopefully someone will clarify on that issue.